# Two folders with almost same code (due to legacy issues), now need to source both of these in another file, getting lot of name conflicts c++

Tags: c++

I have two folders with cloned code with very few differences. We need to keep these folders separate( Can not merge the code ) now we have to use a .h file from both of these folders in another file

folder 1/file1.h

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;

class A{}
```

folder 2/file2.h

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;

class B{}

final file :
#include "file1.C"
#include "file2.C"

A aa();    
B bb();
```

---

In compile, we get the error that ulong has been defined before.

We can not rename "typedef ulong above " or merge codes due to some historical reasons.
How can we get over this problem  without renaming ulong

1. One solution is renaming
2. Any other option

Comment: Use namespaces??

Comment: Code in question needs a bit of clean-up. For example. I'm pretty sure `final file :` is not intended to be in a code block and you aren't including c files.

Comment: If you’re afraid to refactor your code, you won’t get far.

Comment: Move the typedef into a third file, with run-of-the-mill `ifndef/define` guards?